# Error messages when installing OSMnx and GeoPandas

Tags: pip, gdal, geopandas, osmnx, fiona

Hello I am trying to install OSMnx and GeoPandas using pip install osmnx and pip install geopandas (according to this link: https://geoffboeing.com/2016/11/osmnx-python-street-networks/) It says that in order to use OSMnx you have to install geopandas and rtree first, rtree was installed with no issues, but this happened when trying to install osmnx (actually I tried to install osmnx before I found out that I need to install geopandas, I am giving this error here in order to give you as much information as possible)

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\hodor\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Hodor\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m1_7rif2\\Shapely\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Hodor\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m1_7rif2\\Shapely\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Hodor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m1_7rif2\Shapely\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: C:\Users\Hodor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m1_7rif2\Shapely\
Complete output (9 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Hodor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m1_7rif2\Shapely\setup.py", line 80, in <module>
    from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
  File "C:\Users\Hodor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m1_7rif2\Shapely\shapely\_buildcfg.py", line 200, in <module>
    lgeos = CDLL("geos_c.dll")
  File "c:\users\hodor\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] Given module was not found
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

What shall I do (I do NOT want to install anaconda, so if there is a way of avoiding anaconda I would be very happy)?

Any help appreciated, thank you very much

EDIT: OK I tried the steps explained in the question mentioned as a duplicate of my question, I was able to install fiona following these steps but when I typed pip install geopandas I got this new error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\hodor\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Hodor\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5yg59bp6\\shapely\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Hodor\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5yg59bp6\\shapely\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Hodor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5yg59bp6\shapely\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: C:\Users\Hodor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5yg59bp6\shapely\
Complete output (9 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Hodor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5yg59bp6\shapely\setup.py", line 80, in <module>
    from shapely._buildcfg import geos_version_string, geos_version, \
  File "C:\Users\Hodor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5yg59bp6\shapely\shapely\_buildcfg.py", line 200, in <module>
    lgeos = CDLL("geos_c.dll")
  File "c:\users\hodor\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] Uvedený modul nebyl nalezen
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

EDIT 2: Even though the cmd wrote "succesfully installed fiona" when I tried to run simple Attempt.py

```py
import fiona
```

I got this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Hodor\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.41019\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\Hodor\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.41019\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 432, in main    
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Hodor\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.10.41019\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Users\Hodor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Hodor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Hodor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Hodor\Desktop\Untitled-1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import fiona
  File "C:\Users\Hodor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 87, in <module>
    from fiona.collection import BytesCollection, Collection
  File "C:\Users\Hodor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\fiona\collection.py", line 9, in <module>
    from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
ImportError: DLL load failed: Module not found
```

This may also help with troubleshooting of my issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install Fiona on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50876702/cant-install-fiona-on-windows)

Comment: Even though I tried to avoid it I Installed Anaconda and then it was OK, just by conda install geopandas and conda install osmnx

Answer (score 1):

It can be really difficult to install the geospatial dependencies with pip, primarily due to Fiona in my experience. If you can use conda, it's strongly recommended to follow the install instructions in the [OSMnx documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

> If you have any trouble with the installation, try installing OSMnx in a new, clean conda environment using conda-forge and strict channel priority:

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority python=3 osmnx
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it to install using conda and it worked, but the problem is that I need to integrate osmnx with another python package, which I already had huge problems to install using pip in the past. And pip does not see packages installed by conda (see my other question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384226/is-there-a-way-a-pip-list-could-see-a-conda-list )