# Is there a way a pip list could see a conda list?

Tags: python, pip, conda

Hello I have asked a question about handling error messages when pip installing python packages, I was able to solve the question, I did not want to rewrite or delete the question in case anyone needed it.
I tried to install the package needed using Anaconda (I wanted to avoid that but it was the easiest way to install my packages)

But the problem is that I have other python interpreter installed with some other packages I need ( I installed them using pip, because these packages couldn't have been installed using conda but that's different story) and what I need is to "unite" the packages installed with conda with those installed with pip Is there a way I can do it?

Or maybe in other words, is there a way how to make pip to see the conda installed packages when i paste into cmd this?

```
pip list
```

Sorry for maybe a dumb question, but I would be grateful for any help

EDIT: Or maybe in other words one more time, could this problem be solved by adding python module to path somehow? Thank you

Comment: While yes, you can go all Dr. Frankenstein by using [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), I'd strongly recommend you instead take the time to learn best practices, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/57814509/570918. The proper solution is that you create an isolated environment that has both the Conda and the Pip installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `conda list` instead of `pip list`

But I am not sure if `conda list` includes all the `pip` installed packages